# How to get all entries from the database table using Take and Skip methods?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In our current application we have following functionality in Data layer:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(IPagedAndFilteredAndSortedRequest request)
{
    var users = dbContext.Users;
    //1) "filteredAndSorted" is a result of applying filters and sorts on users
    //2) "filteredAndSorted" is OrderedQueriable
    //3) "rows" is number of rows to skip based on request.PageSize and request.PageNumber
    var result = filteredAndSorted.Skip(rows).Take(request.PageSize);
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

And we need to get **all** users from the database using **this method**. So, the questions are:

1. Is it a good idea to pass 1 as **pageNumber** and Int32.MaxValue as **pageSize**?
2. What is the maximum number of rows in MSSQL database table?

Comment: 'What is the maximum number of rows in MSSQL database table?' Just Google it, my dude / dudette! See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 answer: 'Limited by available storage'

Comment: If you want to get all the records in one request, just don't use `.Skip` and `.Take`.

Comment: Get rid of that nasty `ToArray()` call. It's a huge waste of memory and cpu time. Additionally, if you're pre-sorting the data in this method you want to return `IOrderedEnumerable`.

Comment: Apart from whether (and why) you should want to get all rows through an EF query, Yes, option 1 is actually the only option if the `GetUsers` method is a given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to pass 1 as pageNumber and Int32.MaxValue as pageSize?

Not really.  It would be best to add another property to the `request`, something like

```
var result = filteredAndSorted;
if (request.UsePaging)
{
  result = filteredAndSorted.Skip(rows).Take(request.PageSize);
}

return result.ToArray();
```

Or use `request.PageSize` < 1 to turn off paging.